# Perl select function hanging indefinitely

Tags: perl, freetds

I am sorry for this really basic question but I do not seem to find root cause of my issue.

Environment details:
Perl 5.14.1
Connecting to MS SQL Server via freeTDS tsql
Linux x64

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use IO::Select;
use strict;

my $query = "";
my $s = IO::Select->new();
$s->add(\*STDIN);
my @STD_IN = ();
if ($s->can_read(.5)) {
      @STD_IN = <STDIN>;
        }
$query .= "@STD_IN\n@ARGV";

my $myTmpFile = `mktemp /tmp/$ENV{USER}QueryXXXX`; chomp($myTmpFile);
`echo "use testDB\n$dbQuery\ngo\nquit" > $myTmpFile`;

print(`/usr/bin/tsql -H myhost -p 9999 -U myuser -P mypass -o q < $myTmpFile`);
```

When I run this script, like this

```
$>./myscript "select * from mytable"
```

it works fine sometimes but often I see the script hanging indefninitly.

I did some debugging by running `ps -ef` here is how it looks:

```
kedar 24659 24574  0 05:50 ttyp3    00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl -w /home/kedar/myscript select * from mytable
```

What can be the cause for hang here? I do not understand yet - it is a very simple script.

I checked the perl documentation for IO::Select and this is what it says -

```
can_read    

$s->can_read([timeout])
Returns array of handles that are ready for reading. timeout is the maximum amount of time to wait before returning an empty list. If timeout is not given, and any handles are registered, then the call blocks.
```

But I do have timeout in my script.

Any idea? Please help as I am stuck with issue

PS: Some variables, filenames and other things have been modified from original due to few constraints. 
Also, this script is written by someone else previously and I need to fix the hang first. So if you can think of alternate and clean way of doing this - it would be great !

Comment: Why are you not using [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI)?

Comment: This is not a basic question.

Comment: @TLP: Can i connect to MSSQL Server using DBI ?

Comment: ... and, Yes, DBI plays rather well with MSSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@STD_IN = <STDIN>` reads from the filehandle `STDIN` in list context, meaning it will block until it receives an `eof` on the filehandle. The functions of `IO::Select`, on the other hand, will just tell you if there is *any* input on the selected filehandle, not whether it contains all the input.

So in this case you want to read `STDIN` in scalar context(<sup>*</sup>). It could look something like this:

```
if ($s->can_read(.5)) {
    push @STD_IN, scalar <STDIN>;
    # check if there is more than one line of input ready ...
    while ($s->can_read(0)) {
        push @STD_IN, scalar <STDIN>;
    }
}
```

(*) - scalar context might not be sufficient here, either. Scalar context will read from the filehandle up until the next end-of-line character or character sequence. For buffered input or unstructured input, `IO::Select` might tell you that input is available but that input might not contain a new line, and a `scalar <STDIN>` call will block. In that case, you may have to resort to loading input one character at a time (with `getc`, or `read/sysread`) or, if your OS supports it, setting up a non-blocking filehandle.

Answer (score 2):

It might be hung waiting for STDIN as others have suggested, but one other thing to look into: are you sure that it is not the tsql command that is hanging? When you see a hung perl process, do you ALSO see a hung tsql process?

With backtick, the command is run synchronously, and control is not handed back to the next line of your Perl script until that command finishes. So if that hangs, your perl script will hang too, waiting for that tsql system command to finish.

Comment: I checked, tsql does not seem to be hanging when Perl is hanged. Specifically, I do not see tsql under ps -ef output. So apparently it is indeed hung in STDIN

Answer (score 1):

This code is (conditionally) trying to read from standard input, i.e. you, where it says`<STDIN>`. The "hang" is waiting for you to type something. Or more likely this code was designed to have something piped into it. Try typing ctrl-d next time it "hangs", to verify.

Comment: Well, the documentation says if you specify the timeout value, it will not hang

Answer (score 0):

```
./myscript "select * from mytable"
```

Inside double quotes "*" is expanded by Bash to a list of files in the current directory. Use single quotes to use the string verbatim.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But i have seen the issue even when i do something like "select col1 from mytable"